# how to select a div from multiple div on jquery click event if all div have same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with a class `.display_noti` and inside it I have `append` another `div` with class `.palnotific` by jquery.I have fetched data from database and i converted that fetched data into `json_encode`.I used that json format data and made some information which were `append` on that div with class `.palnotific`.

my first jquery code which append data inside that div with class `.display_noti` looks like :-

```
  $.getJSON("notification.php",function(data){  
    // you can do checking here
    if ( data.result && data.result.length > 0 ) {
       $(".display_noti").empty(); // Clear out the div  
       $.each(data.result,function(){  
         $(".display_noti").append("<div class='palnotific'>You got a pal requet from <strong>"+this['from_user']+"</strong><br><span class='date'>"+this['notification_date']+"<form method='post'><input type='text' class='palid' value='"+this['pals_id']+"'></form></div>");
       }); 
       done();
    }
    else {
          $(".display_noti").append("<div class='palnotific' style='background-color:white;'>You have no notification to view.</div>");
    }
```

Above I first get the json format data and I did some validation and then at last I append that second div with class `.palnotific` inside that first div with a class `.display_noti`.I have a form inside that append div which I use to take value from a input for use.

As we know `.palnotific` is an appended div.I wanted to use some Onclick event function on it so, I used below code :-

```
   $('body').on('click','.palnotific',function(){
   var x = $(this).closest('.display_noti').find('.palid');
   var pid=x.val();  
  $.ajax({
    url:'notifipro.php',
    type:'post',
    data:"palid="+pid,
    success: function(data){
      if(data==1)
        {
         $(window).load('oldpage.php');
        }
      if(data==2)
         {
            $(window).load('newpage.php');
         } 

  } 
  });

});
```

Above code takes the input value from that form which was inside that `.palnotific` div which was appended from jquery at previous.As you know those appended div carry data from database via `json_encode`.It will take value as much as available in database which mean if there's 2 data in database json_encode will also have 2 data and those append div class which takes data from json_encode will append 2 time that div with a class `palnotific`.Now my problem is that if i have two div with class `palnotifi` origin from that append my click function work for first div only and when i click on second div `onclick` function doesn't work.No matter I have 2 or more then two div if I click any one div first div click function takes action.How can I make work `onclick` function to those div only which have been clicked?

Comment: If you could paste your code in to a sample jsfiddle that might help some people get you a solution.

Comment: @BryanRay can u select one div from a group of div having same class by jquery `onclick` function?I want to select and take action those divs only which has been clicked  so any idea how can we do it from jquery?

Comment: This would be much easier to understand if you just show what the output HTML looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to have jquery react on an element that is dynamically created, is to attach the event to that element itself. Another way would be using `on` on a the container div with a subfilter, but since you are already creating the html, you can encapsulate it in `$('yourhtml')` and attach the click directly to that created element. In combination with appendTo instead of append, you can also chain the append and click:

```
//mock data:
var data={result: [
          {from_user: 'A',  notification_date: new Date(), pals_id: 1},
          {from_user: 'B',  notification_date: new Date(), pals_id: 2},
          {from_user: 'C',  notification_date: new Date(), pals_id: 3} 
]};


$.each(data.result,function(){  
        var id = this.pals_id;
         $("<div class='palnotific'>You got a pal request from <strong>"+this['from_user']+"</strong><br><span class='date'>"+this['notification_date']+"<form method='post'><input type='text' class='palid' value='"+ id +"'></form></div>")
         .appendTo(".display_noti")
         .click(function(){
             //attach pre existing function or assign your logic here
            alert('You clicked '  + id);
        })
});
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1tLk5n7/)

In this example, the id was also stored before hand and reused inside the attached click. If you need to use the raw value, you can use `$(this).find('.palid').val()` (as done in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1tLk5n7/2/) )

Comment: It did my work bro thanks! So, we use `appendTo`  to append every div with class `.palnotific`  a click function right bro?

Comment: Yep, because appendto still returns the original jquery object. You could also have a variable which contains the created div and use that to append(to) and attach the click to, but this way they can be chained.

Comment: returns original jquery object mean bro?

Comment: that means that objectA.appendTo(objectB) returns objectA. In this case $(somehtml)

Answer (score 1):

From the code you paste, the problem should be this line:

```
var pid=x.val();
```

as you can find in jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> .val()   Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more specific [CSS3 Selector](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) in the `on()` function. I'm not entirely sure this is going to solve your overall problem, but it might lead you in the right direction.

```
$(".display_noti").on("click", ".palnotific:first", function(event) {
  console.log("You Clicked: ", event.target.id);
});
```

Here is an [example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/c4kLkf0s);